# Why is React-Testing-Library / Jest receiving DOM input backwards?

Tags: reactjs, dom, jestjs, react-testing-library

When testing a form, I am using userEvent to type 'hello' into a textbox, then when testing the value of said textbox straight after, using toHaveValue(), it returns the string backwards...

```
 render(<Form />)
 userEvent.clear(screen.getAllByRole('textbox')[0])
 userEvent.type(screen.getAllByRole('textbox')[0], 'hello')
 expect(screen.getAllByRole('textbox')[0]).toHaveValue('hello')
```

The error in console after running yarn test:
[image]

Package versions:

```
    "react-scripts": "^3.4.3",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.1.9",
```

Comment: Can you provide a codesandbox to reproduce this?

Comment: There is a known issue for this: https://github.com/testing-library/user-event/issues/369 But this should have bin resolved in 12.0.4 already.

Comment: I'm having the same issue when working on a SharePoint Framework project. I'm thinking there is _some_ dependency conflict which causes this. But it's pretty difficult to pinpoint :/

Comment: Cannot reproduce it elsewhere, but I am going to presume it is an issue with CRA and its jest dependancy. Quite frustrating -.-

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the same thing, and I was previously on jest ^24.8.0, and after upgrading to the latest (jest ^27.2.1) the issue was resolved.

Comment: Confirming this fixed the issue for me as well.